# Область на карте искомого объекта

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

На карте есть строка поиска, задача задать область на карте, где предположительно находится искомый объект?
Изначально карта инициализируется с координатами Москвы, дальше устанавливаем координаты(область) Уфы. Далее вводим в поиск например "менделеева" и видим все подсказки для Москвы, а надо для Уфы. Любые подсказки примеры.... спасибо!!!



Почему Москва, а не сразу Уфа?!
При создании карты по умолчанию центр указываю Москву

```
   var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });
```

далее после добавления объектов на карту позиционирую карту

```
  myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {
    checkZoomRange: true,
    useMapMargin: true
  });
```

вот и получается сначала Москва, а потом Уфа (Уфа-это пример, город может быть любой).

Есть вариант сразу передать г.Уфа

```
var myMap;
ymaps.geocode('Уфа').then(function (res) {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
        zoom : 10
    });
});
```

но в этом случае, не понятно как быть с одноименными городами
Например г.Советск
Есть 3 Советска - в Тульской, Калининградской и Кировской областях.

Поэтому хотелось бы отталкиваться от объектов на карте и на основе их передавать область для поиска.

Comment: вот мой код: http://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/bmk2puvr/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так, может кому пригодится...

```
  myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {
    checkZoomRange: true,
    useMapMargin: true
  })
    .then(function(){
      //подключаю строку поиска с подсказками SuggestView
    myMap.controls.add(SearchCtrl);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем Москва а потом Уфа. Может сразу Уфа?

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
  center: [54.734773, 55.957829],
  zoom: 9,
  controls: []
});
```

p.s. или у control.SearchControl есть такой параметр: parameters.options.boundedBy

из документации YandexMapAPI:

> parameters.options.boundedBy это Прямоугольная область на карте, где предположительно находится искомый объект. При ранжировании объекты, находящиеся внутри указанной области, будут получать больший приоритет.

Comment: отредактировал свой вопрос, указал почему сначала Москва, а потом Уфа